# Regex find function in different codestyles

Tags: regex

given this sample text:

```
function foo()
foo: function()
foo()
```

I need to match the first 2 row and avoid the last one.
Actually I'm using this `(on\s)?foo(:\sf)?` but this is matching `foo` on the last row.

Since I use this regex to find functions in my text editor, I don't care too much about the effective selection (the editor outputs the line number when the regex matches, which is what I need).

Suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to match only the `foo` function or anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using two `?` quantifiers, this allows the match of `foo` alone.

You could write the regex differently using a 'or' :

```
((on\sfoo)|(foo:\sf))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this requires me to write 2 times the function name. Would be awesome if i could write it only one time.

Comment: Well, so far this seems to be the only way to achieve what I need. Thanks again

Comment: @S1cK94 : You're welcome. I'm searching for a way to improve the regex but didn't find one yet. If I find anything, I'll update.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the way you are doing it, but you could do something like this I suppose: `(?=[^\n\{;]*function)(?=[^\n\{;]*foo:?)[^\n\{;]*` where `[^\n\{;]` contains the things you want to break up the matches... this is basically just checking that `function` and `foo` both exist between those things you want to break the match up... I'd honestly just do something like the answer above.